# How to find all files recursively except those in a certain directory

Tags: shell, find

How can I find all files in a directory recursively, except those in the `.git` directory?

I tried the folowing: `find . \! -name ".*"` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
find . -name '.git' -prune -o -print
```

`-prune` as an action will cause the matched directories to be "pruned" from the search tree, i.e. they won't be searched.

Comment: `-o` is the POSIX-compliant of `-or` (the logical or). So basically, find is looking for *something named .git*, but prune it, or *anything else*, and then print it. `-print` is the default expression that is normally omitted from typical find calls. @scrrr

Comment: @slhck: Didn't know that. Thanks!